# notepad++ How to assign two macro to same key?

Tags: macros, notepad++

Using the GUI: I assigned a macro to allow me to select the current line my cursor is on. I assigned it to 'ctrl+a', and reassigned 'select all' to 'ctrl+alt+a'. I now want, when I press 'ctrl+a' a second time, to have it highlight the remainder of the paragraph. Currently these commands are available via the following key-press:

Instruction:
1. Home->shift+end --highlights one line
2. Home->shift+end->shift+end -- highlights connected lines

So 1. is assigned to 'ctrl+a', but I'm stuck at this point. How do I assign ctrl+a when hit a second time to highlight the connected lines/paragraph? Details/specifics in layman's terms would be appreciated. Again, I've only been using the gui options, I'm not familiar with the more codey options. Note that it doesn't allow me to use
ctrl+a->shift+end.

I'm not overly familiar with macro and hotkey binding, so I'm unaware if this is a limitation or if there's a workaround, other than writing a program to fix it.

Not a coder, but from what I know of Lua I cameup with:

is_press=false
if btn(ctrl+a) and !is_press then btn(Home->shift+end) is_press=true end
if btn(ctrl+a) and is_press then btn(Home->shift+end->shift+end) is_press=false end

I could assign 2. to ctrl+shift+a, as a separate macro if all else fails.

Answer (score 1):

Short answer, I don't think this is possible with a singe shortcut/macro.

Behind the scenes, Scintilla is doing the selecting. Once you've done the selection, going back to "home" the second time will reset the word wrap extension.

Comment: Would an outside program like autohotkey work? I'm not familiar with the general rules of macro/hotkey etc.

Comment: Probably! AutoHotKey is pretty nifty. It has conditionals which might be able to do this behavior. See `A_PriorHotkey`. But search around, I'm sure it is a solved problem.